# Swift 3 simple search engine

Tags: arrays, string, swift3

I have an array of Strings containing user inputted values. I have a string containing several words (the number of words in the string varies). I want to increment an Int every time one of the words in the string matches a word in the array.

I'm using this method:

```
var searchWordsArr: [String] = [] \\filled by user input

var message: String = "" \\random number of words

var numRelevantWords = 0

var i = 0

while i < self.searchWordsArr.count {
    i+=1
    if message.contains(self.searchWordsArr[i-1]) {
        numRelevantWords += 1
    }
}
```

In my first example, the string contained 25 words and the array contained 3 words. The 3 words came up a total of 12 times in the string. Using the above method, the value of numRelevantWords was 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regex. Some day soon, Swift will have native regular expressions. But until it does, you have to resort to Foundation:

```
let words = ["the", "cat", "sat"]
let input = "The cat sat on the mat and the mat sat on the catastrophe"
var result = 0

let pattern = "\\b(" + words.joined(separator:"|") + ")\\b"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let match = regex.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))
    result += match.count // 7, that's your answer
} catch {
    print("illegal regex")
}
```

Comment: The thing that's nice about regex is (1) it knows what a "word" is, and (2) it answers your question ("[how many times] one of the words in the string matches a word in the array") in a _single_ command.

Answer (score 1):

Add them to a NSCountedSet:

```
let searchWords = NSCountedSet()
searchWords.add("Bob")
searchWords.add("John")
searchWords.add("Bob")
print(searchWords.count(for: "Bob")) // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

"pure" Swift (no Foundation)

```
let message = "aa bb aaaa ab ac aa aa"
let words = message.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
let search:Set = ["aa", "bb", "aa"]

let found = words.reduce(0) { (i, word) -> Int in
    var i = i
    i += search.contains(word) ? 1 : 0
    return i
}

print(found, "word(s) from the message are in the search set")
```

prints

```
4 word(s) from the the message are in the search set
```

UPDATE (see discussion)

using Set

```
var search: Set<String> = []  // an empty set with Element == String
search.insert("aa")           // insert word to set
```

using Array

```
var search: Array<String> = [] // an empty array
search.append("aa")            // append word to array
```

maybe you are looking for

```
let message = "the cat in the hat"
let words = message.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
let search:Set = ["aa", "bb", "pppp", "the"]

let found = search.reduce(0) { (i, word) -> Int in
    var i = i
    i += words.contains(word) ? 1 : 0
    return i
}

print(found, "word(s) from the search set found in the message")
```

prints

```
1 word(s) from the search set found in the message
```

if you would like to produce the same as with accepted answer

```
let words = ["the", "cat", "sat"]
let input = "The cat sat on the mat and the mat sat on the catastrophe"

let inputWords = input.lowercased().characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
let found = inputWords.reduce(0) { (i, word) -> Int in
    var i = i
    i += words.contains(word.lowercased()) ? 1 : 0
    return i
}

print(found, "word(s) from the search set found in the message")
```

prints

```
7 word(s) from the search set found in the message
```

Comment: given that my current set of search words are in an array, how can I convert this to a Set? The search words are coming in from various text fields and being appended to the array

Comment: use the Array or Set, the resulting number will be the same

Comment: using Set means, that search.contains() works more effective. appending Element to Set or Array using different syntax.

Comment: Since my search words are in an array, and the data is being appended by an outside source (not implicitly stated as "aa", "bb", "aa") I don't understand how I can use your example without converting the existing array into a set. I'm not familiar with set syntax

Comment: Thanks but that's not doing what I need. The string in the array I'm checking against contains several words. this only works for me with exact matches where I'm checking 1 word against 1 word

Comment: for instance if the keyword is "the" and the string in the array is "the" this works. However, if the string in the array is "the cat in the hat", this doesn't work

Comment: @froggomad it returns 2 words from the search set found in the message, if "the" is in the set, otherwise 0. The same if you use an Array and not Set. What do you expect as a result?

Comment: @froggomad ok, the message is little bit unclear :-). what do you expect as a result?

Comment: I'm looking for what your first example should produce, and does in a playground. In my code it wasn't working at all unless the strings matched exactly. The regex example provided by matt works perfectly. Thanks very much for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144135/discussion-between-user3441734-and-froggomad).